Why is the bslib popover not working in R Shiny?
On clicking the "Click Me!" button, I should see a popover with the selectInput widget. But it is not working. Could anyone let me know as why this is not working?
ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel(
      popover(
        shiny::actionButton("btn_1","Click Me!"),
        selectInput('Species', 'Select Species', as.character(unique(iris$Species))),
        title = "Plot settings"
        ),
      plotOutput("plt")
      )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


popover requires Bootstrap 5, whereas basicPage is using version 3. You need to change your page to version 5.

Can popover be implemented with fluidRow?

I don't know why the popover is not showing but when you are using bslib package try to use everything from the same package. shiny and bslib don't work very well together.
If you replace basicPage from shiny with any page_* function from bslib it should work.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fluid(
  mainPanel(
    popover(
      shiny::actionButton("btn_1","Click Me!"),
      selectInput('Species', 'Select Species', as.character(unique(iris$Species))),
      title = "Plot settings"
    ),
    plotOutput("plt")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

